# Why does printf() print 21 instead of 11 when given a bitmask for 3?

Tags: c

The point of this excercise is to print a binary representation of a number.

Given the following code, I get 00000000000000000000000000000021 printed instead of the expected 00000000000000000000000000000011 when I run print_binary(3).

I think I'm missing something here. Can someone please explain why I get such an unexpected result?

I'm using gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1). To test this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define INT_BITS sizeof(int) * 8

unsigned int check_bit(unsigned int bit, unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int mask = (1 << bit);
    return n & mask;
}

void print_binary(unsigned int num) {
    int bits[INT_BITS];
    for (int i = INT_BITS - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%u", check_bit(i, num));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: return (n & mask) > 0;

Comment: Get into the habit of putting parenthesis around macro replacements, you'll thank yourself later on ... `#define INT_BITS (sizeof(int) * 8)`

Answer (score 3):

Because when `check_bit()` works on bit `1` you get:

```
unsigned int mask = (1 << 1);
return 3 & 2;    /* n & mask => result is b11 & b10 which is b10 which is decimal 2 */
```

So `2` gets print using the `unsigned` specifier, hence you get `..021` and not `..011`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
n >> bit & 1
```

For e.g

```
unsigned int check_bit(unsigned int bit, unsigned int n) {
    return n >> bit & 1;                                  
}
```